# Show $A_n$ has no subgroup of index $n$ for $n\geq 5$ (or find a counterexample)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show $A_n$ has no subgroup of index $n$ for $n\geq 5$.

Assume such a subgroup $H$ exists. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all left cosets of $H$ in $A_n$. Let $A_n$ act on $\mathcal{A}$ by left-multiplication, and let $\pi:A_n\to\text{Sym}(\mathcal{A})=S_n$ be the associated permutation representation. Since $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$, either $\ker\pi$ is trivial or $\ker\pi=A_n$. We proceed by cases. Suppose $\ker\pi=A_n$. Then $aH=H$ for all $a\in A_n$. This means there is only one coset of $H$ in $A_n$, which implies $H=A_n$. This is a contradiction since $[A_n:H]=n$. Now assume $\ker\pi$ is trivial. Then $\pi$ is injective, so $A_n\cong\text{im }\pi$.

> I am not sure what to do from here. Any advice?

EDIT: Is $A_6$ with the subgroup $A_5$ a counterexample? Does the whole "subgroups of index $n$ of $S_n$ are isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$" thing hold for $A_n$ as well? Maybe this is related to the fact that $A_n\cong\text{im }\pi$.

Comment: Where did you get this problem?

Comment: Technically the question allowed for counterexamples, but I couldn't immediately think of any. However, I believe I may have just found one.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that the question was supposed to read  *.... no subgroup of index $<n$...*

Comment: Ah yes, that would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is a counterexample for all $n$, namely $A_{n-1}$ in $A_n$, since $A_{n-1}$ has order $\frac{(n-1)!}2$ and $A_n$ has order $\frac{n!}2$.